# regular expression to match everything between two words

Tags: regex, tcl

Writing a TCL script to match everything in between two key words

Example:

```
X509v3 Extended Key Usage:

1.2.3.4, 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.4, 1.1.1.1, 234.432.1.36.4564.345

55.55.55.55, 66.66.66.66, 1234.5443.123.321.12.332.231.1

X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
```

I want to be able to get all the information in between Extended Key Usage and Subject Key Identifier.

```
1.2.3.4, 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.4, 1.1.1.1, 234.432.1.36.4564.345

55.55.55.55, 66.66.66.66, 1234.5443.123.321.12.332.231.1
```

What I have tried without success:

```
set content [regexp {(?=<Extended Key Usage)(?s)(.*)(?=X509)} $ext match]
.
set content [regexp {\y(Extended Key Usage)(.*)(X509)\y} $ext match]
```

Comment: I tried this.. /Key Usage:(.*)X509v3/ and it seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
regexp -linestop {Extended Key Usage:\s.*[\r\n]+((?:.|[\r\n])*?)(?=\s*X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:)} $subject regexmatch result
```

Try this. The result is captured in capturing group 1. Lookbehind is **not** supported in TCL ARE http://wiki.tcl.tk/461